# What is magnetic flux made of?

Tags: magnetic-fields

Assuming we're talking about a magnet in a perfect vacuum.

What exactly is the magnetic flux/field?

If it is not matter, it is a form of energy, but energy is a rather vague term; what is it really?

Comment: I don't think you will receive a satisfying answer here. It seems to me that this is rather a philosophical question.

Comment: You will benefit from reading this other thread https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/13157/what-is-a-field-really

Comment: The idea is that we define things in terms of what they do, rather than what they "really" are. Magnetic field is something ([a force field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force_field_(physics))) that will exert a force on moving charges and magnetic dipoles. Electric charge is a property that some particles have that causes them to experience a force when placed in an electromagnetic field.

Answer (score 2):

It is a ***field***.

Fields are currently the most fundamental objects known to physics. For example, all known particles are actually the (quantum) excitations of some field.

Comment: This answer seems really vague!

Comment: It provides a perfectly fine answer. The question asks what the magnetic field is made of. The answer is that is a fundamental object and therefore not made of anything. In fact, all other `things' in nature are made out of fields in some way or other.

Comment: This is not vague and it is *the* answer to the question. Fields are fields. They are not something else. And yes, for many of us that notion feels *wrong* when we first encounter it, but it is *still* the answer.

Comment: The problem with ignorance (refering to mine) is that it is often hard to formulate a proper question. Reading the other question which I marked my question as a duplicate, the question I wanted to ask was: what material is a field made of?

Comment: And the answer is nothing. A field is (as far as we know) a fundamental object, it is not made of anything. In fact, the opposite seems to be true all other things are made out of fields. I agree this may not be easy to wrap your head around, but it is the core of the matter.