# What is a Field? Do all things have them? What types of fields are there?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, field-theory, wave-particle-duality

All “things” have wave properties, & waves operate in fields, so all things have fields, yes? What types of fields (i.a.EM, gravity, Energy) do all things have? Does each type of Field associate with a specific radial distance, velocity or “origin point of emission”?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/13157/2451 and links therein.

Comment: The [Standard Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) has seventeen quantum fields.

Comment: Wouldn’t that depend on whether you give each coloured quark its own field or not?