# Are mediums fields?

Tags: waves, field-theory, terminology

I understand that, at the more fundamental physical level, waves are phenomena of [Fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(physics)). Like electromagnetic waves of the electromagnetic field.

However, I also know that we can have waves in [Mediums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_medium). Like water waves in ocean water.

So, are those mediums, a kind of field? Is the ocean a field?

I'm a bit confused as to how to properly use both terms in physics.

Comment: This is a technicality but I would not consider a medium a field. For gravity waves in water (not to be confused with gravitational waves), it is the height of the surface that is a field not water itself.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/13157/50583

Answer (score 12):

No.

It is incorrect to say that a medium "is" a field. A medium is often conveniently *described by* properties that are fields. Like density, pressure, displacement, concentration of certain chemicals etc.

Also note that the description of a medium by a field may be just one among others. For example, you can study the deformation of a solid using its displacement field and the continuum theory of elasticity, while there also is the description in terms of lattice models. The latter would be discrete and not involve a field to describe the deformation of the medium.

Answer (score 7):

[Field (physics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(physics)):

> In physics, a field is a physical quantity, represented by a scalar, vector, or tensor, that has a value for each point in space and time.

So yes, indeed, (continuous) distributions of density, pressure, etc. in continuous media are fields. Moreover, in hydrodynamics and elasticity they obey well-known *[field equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_equation)*. In condensed matter physics some of these the fields are even quantized - like [phonons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonon) (vibration quanta), [plasmons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasmon) (quanta of hydrodynamic plasma oscillations), etc.