# What will happen to the the various fields of the universe after heat death?

Tags: gravity, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, field-theory, universe

What will happen to the various fields like the electromagnetic field, gravitational field etc that make up the universe after heat death? Will they continue existing even after a heat death?

Sorry if the question is naive. If it isn't appropriate for this forum, I will try asking somewhere else.

Comment: You might ask yourself if you think that fields are "real actual things" or just useful tools for describing the relations between "things".  Related reading: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/13157/what-is-a-field-really